# Can anybody help me with the message: "We can no longer accept questions from this account"?

Tags: discussion, support

I've got a message saying "We can no longer accept questions from this account" what questions should I delete or edit? I deleted a few questions, but the rest seems useful.

**Question:** What should I do in order to avoid getting this message again? Are there questions that should be deleted or edited to stop getting this message?

I have other questions to ask about Islam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the [question ban](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) help page and my previous comments have been too subtle.  Here:

## *** *IMPROVE YOUR QUESTIONS THROUGH EDITING*!!!

> We believe asking questions on our site is a privilege, not a right. If, after a few fair attempts, you haven’t been able to prove that your contributions to Stack Overflow make it at least … not-worse … then we reserve the right to refuse your questions. -- [Asking Better Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/), Jeff Atwood, 2010

Go through them one by one (**all of them**), identify how to improve them, and do it.  (Deleting them doesn't resolve the question ban.)

This is already explained on the [question ban](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) help page (which is linked when you receive the question ban message).

I have already tried to help you by:

1. Explaining what's wrong with your posts (both generally, and with 10 example questions) here: [Why do I get this message on Stack Exchange Islam?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3148/17163).
2. Editing some of your questions to make them more suitable, including heavily editing [Can a weak Muslim country at war with a powerful Muslim country seek help from a powerful non-Muslim country?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43311/17163), leaving a comment to explain what I've done to improve it.
3. Upvoting your better questions myself.

In response, I've seen no meaningful effort put into your existing posts, and argumentative comments.  Just in case you missed it above:

## *** *IMPROVE YOUR QUESTIONS THROUGH EDITING*!!!

**If you are unwilling or unable to edit your questions to improve them, then just accept the question ban.**  It literally exists in order to prevent users from posting large numbers of low-quality questions.

Further detail is explained in a [meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

> ### Why am I getting this message?
>
> As stated in the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) links on
>   every page, Stack Exchange is a network of *question and answer
>   sites*, not help forums. This implies that all posts are expected to
>   have some value for later visitors too. To enforce that, and to
>   prevent [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) making
>   the answerers turn away from the communities, low-quality questions
>   and answers are blocked. This includes posts from:
>
> - users who can't be bothered to form sentences
> - users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
> - users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do
>
> Once you have posted too many poorly-received questions or answers,
>   you will be banned from posting more, and you will see the error
>   message.
>
> ### Are deleted posts taken into account too?
>
> If a post was poorly-received (downvoted or closed), that will
>   continue to count against your account **even if the post is
>   deleted!** Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting
>   them.
>
> Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions if less
>   than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into
>   answering or moderating the question.
>
> Finally, deleted
>   answers always count towards an automatic ban on new accounts.
>
> It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of
>   your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently
>   they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from
>   users who read them, edit them, or [respond to
>   them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471).
>   Therefore deleted posts
>   [have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029)
>   an effect on the filter, among many other factors.
>
> Beware that an account might very well have many deleted posts,
>   including [auto-deleted old low-score
>   questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year),
>   all of which are only visible to moderators.
>
> ...
>
> ### How do I avoid getting a question ban?
>
> ... Investigate and
>   search before you ask. Put some effort in your questions.
>
> All questions are expected to have some value for later visitors too.
>   So if *many* of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted,
>   closed, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they
>   did not meet the required quality. Be sure to understand why that
>   happens, and learn from that. Don't simply repost the same question
>   again.
>
> If you're not sure what qualifies as a "good question", there are some
>   hints and tips available:
>
> - [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center
> - [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
>     by Jon Skeet
> - [How to Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by Eric S.
>     Raymond
> - [Getting Answers](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) by Mike Ash
>
> ...

Oh, and:

## *** *IMPROVE YOUR QUESTIONS THROUGH EDITING*!!!

Comment: This is it?I have only 2 questions to edit?

Comment: Let me guess,there are more to edit,right?

Comment: [Your profile](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/23833/alex-a) lists 26 questions.  This won't include deleted questions nor questions from other accounts, which will also affect the question ban.

Comment: After I have edited few of them,can you tell me if it is ok how I edited?

Comment: And what should I do with those questions that you claim that is no research efforts?While they are edited by someone?

Comment: I gave my general advice on [this meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2982/17163).  But at the very least, (a) explain what you know and (b) search for an answer in a search engine and explain how that doesn't resolve the question.

Comment: Can you tell me,how many questions left to correct?And can you please name the questions that are left?

Comment: @AlexA — If I were you, I would not worry about the number of questions to edit. I would focus my effort on editing as many as I can, after posting a [trial run first](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/). Trial runs will help you get your questions refined prior to editing old ones or posting new ones.