# When will the ban message be lifted?

Tags: discussion, support

I have now fixed all my questions, and still I there is ban message? Is the ban message I got is permanently or it is a temporary one? “Because” it passed 3 months I suppose and I want my ban message to be lifted tomorrow. So, can a moderator lift my ban message? Or, how it is set to be my ban message? “Because”, it is getting bored to wait until the ban message is over, I have improved my question. Can you tell me if is even true that I have improved in a proper manner? And, if a moderator can lift the ban message, can any moderator lift my ban message? So that I can learn from my mistake, please? “Because”, I have learned my mistake and if you were to lift my ban message, I will not repeat the same mistakes. Seriously.

Curious to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anybody help me with the message: "We can no longer accept questions from this account"?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3157/can-anybody-help-me-with-the-message-we-can-no-longer-accept-questions-from-th)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, moderators cannot lift your question ban even if they wanted to. It's applied automatically by the system when it sees that you have posted a certain threshold of bad questions (determined in part by vote and close patterns) and can only be lifted by *not* having so many bad questions to cross that threshold.

The fact that you've "fixed" all your questions is an important start, but until the community decides that the questions deserve to be *upvoted* instead of *downvoted*, or *reopened* instead of *closed*, the ban will stay in place. This just takes patience; communities are fickle beasts, and many people just aren't inclined to read through closed questions that have already been heavily downvoted.

If all else fails, six months after your *last* question you'll have the opportunity to post *one* new question. Make it count, and that might be enough to have the ban be lifted permanently.

For more details, read the following:

- [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)
- [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/132874)

Comment: If for example, I asked too many times, and the it contains many wrongs in that very very long text, and this time I ask the same question but this time, I show my work that I have improved in a proper manner, will in that case I don’t get a ban message and plus I will also get a good answer? Out of curiosity